# i'm trying to add a numpy array to a df and it seems to always add it at the end and not as a column

Tags: python, list, numpy

this is what the code looks like. and i have added the output as an image along with a link to all the code [FULL CODE](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1sXFe5e8iZ9iFDjX2jsS6Vmoy4XF9n6WA?usp=sharing)
the output when i print(x) looks like this.
`[[20] [20] [21] ... [50] [49] [49]]`

```
aapl=yf.download('AAPL')
aapl=aapl['Adj Close']
y=(aapl[training_lenth_AAPL:])
y['predit']=x
y.tail()
```

[image]

Comment: `y` is a Series not a Dataframe, as you keep only `Adj Close` column, you don't handle a Dataframe anymore, so there is "add colum" option. Do you see that ?

Comment: Looks like you need to read some more basic `pandas`.  Among other things pay attention to what's a Series, and how that differs from a DataFrame, both in action, and in display.